# Property of normal matrix's eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I prove that, if $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a normal complex matrix (i.e. $AA^H=A^HA$, $A^H$ being the conjugate transpose) and $f$ a rational complex function defined on a subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ containing all the eigenvalues of $A$, and $\tilde{f}$ is the "matrix equivalent" of $f$, i.e., since $f$ being rational must be a ratio of polynomials, the function that swaps the variable $x$ in $f(x)$ with the matrix, calculating the appropriate powers and considering constants $c$ as $cI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and considering negative powers as powers of the inverse matrix, supposing everything works fine (i.e. there are no negative powers of singular matrixes), then there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that:
$$|f(\lambda)|\leq\frac{\|\tilde{f}(A)x\|_2}{\|x\|_2},$$
where $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the euclidean complex norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be normal. There is a unitary $Q$ and a diagonal $\Lambda=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ such that $A=Q\Lambda Q^*$. For normal matrices (if $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ is well-defined on the spectrum of $A$), we have $f(A)=Qf(\Lambda)Q^*$, where $f(\Lambda)=\mathrm{diag}(f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n))$. Note that $f(A)$ is a normal matrix as well.

For any normal matrix, there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, $|\lambda|\leq\|Ax\|_2/\|x\|_2$. This follows simply from the Courant-Fischer characterization, namely
$$\tag{1}
\lambda_{\min}(A^*A)=\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^*(A^*A)x}{x^*x}=\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2^2}
$$
and the fact that for a normal matrix $A$,
$$\tag{2}
\lambda_{\min}(A^*A)=|\lambda_{\min}(A)|^2.
$$
Now plug $f(A)$ instead of $A$ to (1) and (2) and it's done.

Note that $f$ does not need to be necessarily a rational function.

Comment: Uh-huh. But the theorem seems to state its validity for all $x$, not just for eigenvectors. Maybe that's where the normality comes in. Can we say any normal matrix has a basis of eigenvectors? If so, we can write $x=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i$, $v_i$ being the eigenvectors. So we can conclude $f(A)x=sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_if(\lambda_i)v_i$ by your argument. After taking the norm we apply the subadditive property of the norm, getting an inequality. Only it's in the wrong direction. So how do I fix this?

Comment: @MickG Thanks, fixed.